# nlinfit in MatLab receives an unexpected result

Tags: matlab, regression, non-linear-regression

The quiz I met first gave me an Logistic model:
[image]
And ask me to linearize it, then evaluate the value of `a` and `k` according to the data it gave( in this subject `L` is took as `3000`). I finished that, but got into trouble in the second subject which asked me to do a non-linear-regression with `a` and `k`'s value evaluated in the first subject. Here's my code:

```matlab
function y = func(const, t)
  y = const(1)./(1 + const(2)*exp(-const(3)*t));
end
```

```matlab
t = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
y = [43.65,   109.86,   187.21,  312.67,   496.58,  707.65 ,  ... 
     960.25,  1238.75,  1560,    1824.29,  2199,    2438.89,  2737.71];

yAss = log ((3000 ./ y) - 1);
p    = polyfit (t, yAss, 1);
a    = exp (1) ^ (p(2)); 
k    = -p(1);

beta0 = [3000, a, k];
beta  = nlinfit (t, yAss, @func, beta0);

yAfter   = beta(1) ./ (1 + beta(2) * exp (-beta(3) * t));
yCompare = 3000 ./ (1 + a * exp (-k * t));

scatter (t, y); hold on;
plot (t, yAfter, 'r');
plot (t, yCompare);
```

And what it gave:

[image]

The red curve is generated with the value returned by `nlinfit`, Anyone could tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid... Answering my own question and the question itself is stupid either...

```
beta  = nlinfit (t, yAss, @func, beta0);
```

should be:

```
beta  = nlinfit (t, y, @func, beta0);
```

I really want to delete that question...